Escaping quotes in Javascript
I'm building a list of keywords as buttons.
I want my list to look like this:
<a href='Javascript:false' onclick='filterOnKeyword("Alice")'>Alice</a></span>
<a href='Javascript:false' onclick='filterOnKeyword("Bob")'>Bob</a></span>
etc.

And I'm building it out like this:
function buildKeywordList(keywordArray){
    $.each(keywordArray, function(i,val){
    $(".keyword-list").append("<a href='Javascript:false' onclick='filterkeyword(\'" + val + "\')'>" + val + "</a></span>");
    });
}

But this is what is being rendered:
<a href="Javascript:false" onclick="filterkeyword(" structure')'>structure</a>

Seems to be messing up the order of the quotes.
I tried pulling the string out into a variable, like this:
    var str = "filterkeyword(\'" + val + "\')";
    $(".keyword-list").append("<a href='Javascript:false' onclick='" + str + "'>" + val + "</a></span>");

but it changed nothing.
It's been decades since I had to write code with escaped quotes. Obviously I've forgotten how to do it.
I'd also accept alternate ways of doing this (i.e. ones from the 21st century).

Consider using template string:
$('.keyword-list').append(\${val}`);`

Why is there a closing </span> after each <a>?

You should use real button element...

I would strongly recommend you create real HTML elements (as opposed to strings) and use event delegation to listen for click events.
Then you don't need to worry about any quote escaping or properly encoding text.
As per Mister Jojo's suggestion, a <button> element also makes more sense


const keywordList = document.querySelector('.keyword-list');

// Add a click event handler at the .keyword-list element
keywordList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // check if the event originated within a <button>
  const btn = e.target.closest('button[type=button]');
  if (btn) {
    // pass the text value to your function
    filterOnKeyword(btn.value);
  }
});

function filterOnKeyword(word) {
  console.log('filterOnKeyword', word);
}

function buildKeywordList(keywordArray) {

  // append accepts varargs so map and spread the array
  keywordList.append(
    ...keywordArray.map((value) =>
    
      // create a <button> and assign properties
      Object.assign(document.createElement('BUTTON'), {
        value,
        textContent: value,
        type: 'button',
      }),
    ),
  );
}

buildKeywordList(['Alice', 'Bob']);
.keyword-list {
  display: flex; 
  column-gap: 1rem;
  
  & button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
<div class="keyword-list"></div>



